# Json output file error after upgrading to Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: android-studio

My android app will not longer compile after upgrading to Arctic Fox.  In the idea.log file I find the following warning:  "GradleBuildOutputUtil.kt - Failed to read Json output file from C:\EJW\Programming\Projects\DrillSelector\DrillSelector\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\output-metadata.json. Build may have failed."

The Build Output window in Android Studio gave this error:
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't make a guess for com.xxxx.DrillSelector.databinding.FragmentMainBindingImpl"  followed by

"Cause: couldn't make a guess for com.xxxx.DrillSelector.databinding.FragmentMainBindingImpl".

The error from the idea.log file makes me think that the new version of Android Studio wants to find a file that the older version of Android Studio does not make but I am at loss as to what to do a bout it.  Any suggestions?

Thanks.